# IE 11 Jquery compatablity

Tags: jquery

```
function LoadTabs(taskid, type, element) {

     //  $(".loader").show();
     debugger;
     $.ajax({
         url: '/RenewalLicense/GetSubtabs',
         data: {
             Taskid: taskid,
             Type: type
         },
         type: 'GET',
         //contentType: 'application/html',
         //data: JSON.stringify(model),

         success: function(content) {
             //////////debugger;
             debugger;
             var res = element.replace("litab", "");
             $('a[href="' + res + '"]').tab('show');
             $(element).html(content);

             //$(element).empty().append(content);
             //$("#bar").width(600);
             //$(".loader").fadeOut(3000);

         },
         error: function(e) {
             //////////debugger;
         }
     });
}
```

The above code gives me a error at $(element).html(content);This works perfectly in all other browers

Comment: What error is it getting?

Comment: you might have to console.log(element) before you throw `html` in it